Changing the style of the label of choices as well as page numbering in `exam` document class
This is the first time for me to use exam document class. This document class is nice but I have two questions (or problems). I wrote the following simple quiz
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1.25in, bottom=1in,headsep=30pt,heightrounded
]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\renewcommand\questionlabel{(\thequestion)}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\arabic{question}}

\renewcommand\choicelabel{(\thechoice)}
\renewcommand{\thechoice}{\alph{choice}}

\begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
   \question $\neg \, (p \longleftrightarrow q) \Longleftrightarrow \ldots$
    \begin{oneparchoices}
     \choice $(\neg\,q \vee p) \wedge (p \wedge \neg\,q)$,  
     \choice $\neg\, p \longleftrightarrow \neg\, q$, 
     \choice $\neg\, p \vee \neg\,q$,
     \choice $(q \wedge \neg\, p) \vee (p \wedge \neg\,q)$.
    \end{oneparchoices}
 \end{questions}
\end{document}


How can I make the labels of choices bold (e.g., (a), (b), (c), and (d))?
I noticed that the exam document class replaces the default page numbering (1,2, etc) by Page #N (where #N is the number of the page). This is fine to me. But I wonder why the first page of the exam does not have any numbering (Page 1)?!
Is it possible to change the style of page numbering to be, say, Page 1 of 5, page 2 of 5, and so on?


To print the choice labels in bold, simply define them in \choicelabel to turn out bold via \textbf.
The exam class has a somewhat special handling for headers and footers that allows you to specify different content for the first page. You can set the foot on the first page with \firstpagefooter.
The lastpage package adds the label LastPage that you can use with \pageref to get the last page of the document.
Other notes:

I'd use \textbf{\thequestion} instead of adding \bfseries to \thequestion.
You don't need the inputenc package nowadays.

Combined into an MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{exam}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1.25in, bottom=1in,headsep=30pt,heightrounded
]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\firstpagefooter{}{Page \thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}}{}
\runningfooter{}{Page \thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}}{}

\renewcommand\questionlabel{(\textbf{\thequestion})}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\arabic{question}}

\renewcommand\choicelabel{(\textbf{\thechoice})}
\renewcommand{\thechoice}{\alph{choice}}

\begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
   \question $\neg \, (p \longleftrightarrow q) \Longleftrightarrow \ldots$
    \begin{oneparchoices}
     \choice $(\neg\,q \vee p) \wedge (p \wedge \neg\,q)$,  
     \choice $\neg\, p \longleftrightarrow \neg\, q$, 
     \choice $\neg\, p \vee \neg\,q$,
     \choice $(q \wedge \neg\, p) \vee (p \wedge \neg\,q)$.
    \end{oneparchoices}
 \end{questions}
\end{document}

